# Handling TDataSet results in Xcode from Delphi XE2 Datasnap Server

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, delphi, datasnap

I'm looking at the feasibility of using a Delphi XE2 DataSnap server pushing data from a SQL server through to an iPad application.

I've written the DataSnap server application, and am looking now at the iOS application. The `TServerMethod` returns the data as a `TDataSet` in iOS. What isn't clear is how does one go about extracting the resulting `TDataSet` in Xcode as a `NSMutableArray`? Below is the generated code in the `DSProxy.m`:

```
-(id) getTServerMethods1_GetMileageList {
    return [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
        [DSRESTParameterMetaData parameterWithName: @"Value" withDirection:Input withDBXType:WideStringType withTypeName:@"string"],
        [DSRESTParameterMetaData parameterWithName: @"" withDirection:ReturnValue withDBXType:TableType withTypeName:@"TDataSet"],
    nil];
}
```

Comment: you may want to add or modify your tags to reflect that your issue is related to objective-C

Answer (score 1):

It looks like straight JSON that gets sent down to the client - so you should be able to use existing api's to turn it into NSStrings, NSNumbers, etc. Slightly similar to here: [NSJSONSerialization gives me error "Duplicate key"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9859178/nsjsonserialization-gives-me-error-duplicate-key/9859531#9859531)